XML: Condition for the necessity of an element in an XML schema
Is it possible to specify a condition for the necessity of an element in a complex type in XML based on the presence/absence of a value for an element from another complex type?
For example, there is a questionnaire that needs to be filled out.
XML schema looks as follows:
    <xs:complexType name="Location">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
            <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" /> 
            <xs:element name="ZipCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Person">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Age" type="xs:positiveInteger" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

Is it possible to implement the following conditions in an XML schema of version 1.0:

If the user fills in the Street, then the Address field is required to be filled out;
If the user does not fill in the Street, then the Address field is optional.

I want to understand whether XML version 1.0 allows adding logical conditions based on the case I described

Not in XSD 1.0, though XSD 1.1 asserts will do it.

@YitzhakKhabinsky that should be an answer. (It is correct.)
